# Why do adding jq arguments not change value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm writing a bash script and came across this problem. When I pass `jq` `--arg` flags, it is not updating the value. But when I hard code in the values without the `--arg` flags, it does.

I have tried this in a script, and have also tried this directly in a terminal in both ways (with and without the argument flags). With does not update the value. Without does update the value.

```sh
echo "${JSON}"
[
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "fizz.buzz",
    "protocol": "https",
    "serviceId": "1s1495",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 80
  },
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "foo.bar",
    "serviceId": "1s1499",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 8082
  }
]
```

Works

```sh
jq '.[] | select((.hostname=="foo.bar") and (.targetPort==8082)).serviceId = "123"' <<<"${JSON}" | jq -s
```

Output

```sh
[
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "fizz.buzz",
    "protocol": "https",
    "serviceId": "1s1495",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 80
  },
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "foo.bar",
    "serviceId": "123",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 8082
  }
]
```

Does not work

```sh
jq --arg host "foo.bar" --arg port "8082" --arg id "123" '.[] | select((.hostname==$host) and (.targetPort==$port)).serviceId = $id' <<<"${JSON}" | jq -s
```

Output

```sh
[
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "fizz.buzz",
    "protocol": "https",
    "serviceId": "1s1495",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 80
  },
  {
    "type": "portRule",
    "hostname": "foo.bar",
    "serviceId": "1s1499",
    "sourcePort": 443,
    "targetPort": 8082
  }
]
```

I will note that I am hoping that I can replace even the arguments values with environment variables rather than the strings as my examples shows. But I've tested both ways, same results.

So am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug with `jq` (Probably not).

Expected results. It updates the value in the json with `--arg` flags as it does without and hard coding the strings.

Comment: Your `targetPort` is an *integer*, but your `$port` is a *string*.

Answer (score 2):

Variables passed to jq using `--arg` are all converted to string, you need to use `--argjson` to pass integers.

```
jq --arg host "foo.bar" --argjson port "8082" --arg id "123" '.[] | select((.hostname==$host) and (.targetPort==$port)).serviceId = $id' <<<"${JSON}" | jq -s
```

As a sidenote, you don't need to call jq twice, just use `map`.

```
jq 'map(select(.hostname==$host and .targetPort==$port).serviceId=$id)' --arg host "foo.bar" --argjson port 8082 --arg id "123" <<<"$JSON"
```

Comment: Certainly not the only option; one can also cast the variable after it's in. We already have several duplicates caused by the same bug; should be able to find one with existing answers showing both approaches...